# iPad/iPhone interesting memory observation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a quite a big iPad app and when I run the app in xcode debug mode, it shows about 50 MB in the Activity Monitor and memory grows slowly. (About 0.1 MB per 30 seconds approximately.) But when I run the app directly from the simulator(which is already installed in the simulator) , it shows about 10 MB in the activity monitor and memory is not growing.(its constant). I have checked the performance though the instruments and no leaks showing there.

**Does anyone know for reason to showing different memory details for above 2 scenarios and which one is correct?**

**Also is there a way to programatically print the consumed memory by the app in the console**?

Comment: Is this all from within the Simulator?  You should avoid doing memory tuning in the Simulator, because it provides you with wildly different results than running on an actual device.

Comment: Hi Brad, How do you test the memory with in the actual device? Where do we get the statistical details when running in the device? Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity Monitor is a generally useless way to track memory growth.  There are about a zillion different contributors to RPRVT, some of which are entirely non-intuitive.   Activity Monitor can certainly be used to figure out "uh, oh, it is growing", but not much beyond that.

Use Instruments to track memory growth.

When you say "run in Debug mode", do you have anything configured like zombie tracking or allocation information tracking?  That'll contribute to memory growth.

Beyond that, the Allocation Instrument will generally show you what is contributing to growth.

**Also is there a way to programatically print the consumed memory by the app in the console?**

An absolute number like this isn't very useful.  That an app is growing is bad, but a raw number won't tell you why any more usefully than Activity Monitor.

Use Instruments. :)

Comment: Hi bbum, Thanks for your reply.
yes. I have NSZombieEnabled in my app. I have used instruments. In Leaks it doesn't show anything leaks. 
In Allocations there are quite a large no of allocations and its difficult to identify what contributed to growth at once. Is there a way to clear all the memory snapshot and recapture from the beginning? Then it might be easier to identify the newly allocated objects instead of all the objects allocated from the beginning of the app?

Comment: NSZombieEnabled will cause objects to never be deallocated (unless you set NSDeallocateZombies=NO). It presumably doesn't show up as a leak because it's intentional.

Comment: hi bbum and tc,
I have disabled the NSZombieEnabled. Now it works perfectly. Thank you very much for tip. I didnt know about it. Thanks again

Comment: 'Beyond that, the Allocation Instrument will generally show you waht is contributing to growth' -- How?  When I try to use it, it shows me a thousand little things, but I don't recognize any of it as saying 'aha!  This UIWebView is allocating 5GB's of memory, and is the cause of my memory crash!'

Comment: 1. turn on "track live allocations" (or whatever it is called).  2. Run your app.  3. Sort by the # of bytes column.   That will sort by the type of thing that is responsible for the most amount of memory use.